# Swap div content onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a slider with images in it. When an image is clicked, I would like to use JQuery to swap the image out with an `<iframe>`. When the slideshow is advanced, i'd like to swap it back.

Is this possible? I'm not sure how I would swap an image out with an `iframe`.

EDIT:
I came up with something like this, but it's not working. It kind of expresses what I want to try and do.

```
$("#holdFrame1").click(
         function () {
            $('#holdFrame1').hide();
            var someText = '<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/35534572?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;color=ffffff" width="960" height="540" wmode=transparent frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>';
            var newDiv = $("<div>").append(someText);
                $(this).append(newDiv);
                 })
```

Comment: Well at first glance, it appears you're appending your `<iframe>` to a div (#holdFrame1) that you've just hidden, so you're not going to see it.

Comment: nobody can help without seeing other code events & some html...where would anyone start based on one small snippet??

Comment: Well i'm not sure how it would even be accomplished, if it's even possible. I'm asking if it is possible, and what the structure looks like.

Comment: Most everything is possible! Definitely something like this -- need more code though, what's the slider like? What code determined the "next slide" what does your html markup look like? As SenorAmor mentioned, why are you hiding the #holdFrame1 div?

Comment: The slider is made of images with videos hidden behind them. When the image is clicked, the image is hidden and the video is shown in the exact same spot.

Instead of hiding and showing them, I thought maybe I could just swap the content of the div on a click.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what exactly you need but this might give you clue.

http://jsfiddle.net/jonevar/DG6cn/3/